# How to ensure once-only processing of data in an AWS serverless architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I have some data that needs to be processed at a point in time.

My current strategy is to pull the data every minute and load it into a queue and process it.

I have two concerns with this strategy:

1. I can't guarantee that the last minute captures all data so I pull the last two minutes; and
2. Lambdas as far as I know can fire multiple times depending on the trigger (in this case SQS.)

I'm trying to avoid writing a flag to the data because of the spikey nature of batch processing.

The only other solution I can think of is using S3 to create a lock-file.

Is there a better way to 'kick off' future events? Is there a strategy outside database and S3 flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SQS FIFO Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html), they are designed to deliver once and only once.

> You can now use Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) for applications that require messages to be processed in a strict sequence and exactly once using First-in, First-out (FIFO) queues. FIFO queues are designed to ensure that the order in which messages are sent and received is strictly preserved and that each message is processed exactly once. *[...source](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/)*

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise there was more detail to FIFO. Strict order isn't required but it does have deduplication features! Thank you!